# Print bits from argv

Tags: c, printing, bit, argv

I'm sure the answer is simple but I can't get my head around so I hope you can help me :)

I'm trying to print the bits of a unsigned char, here with the value 2, the issue is that I get a wrong answer when casting from argv[1][0] and the good one when sending directly the number 2.

```
void    print_bits(unsigned char octet)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char   b;

    i = 8;
    while (i--)
    {
        b = (octet >> i & 1) + '0';
        write(1, &b, 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    print_bits((unsigned char)argv[1][0]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    print_bits(2);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

gives me :

```
00110010
00000010
```

I notice when debugging that, if I print the "octet" variable at the start of `print_bits`, I get the ASCII value of 2 when casting from argv and the value "\002" when directly inputting the value 2.
It feels like a casting issue ?
Thank you!

Comment: Characters are represented by their ascii value. If you want to turn a character digit into a corresponding integer value, you subtract the ascii value for the character zero... `print_bits((unsigned char)argv[1][0] - '0');`

Comment: You are printing the bits of the first character of a string. That's of course the ASCII value of the character. If you are sure that it is a digit you can subtract `'0'` from `argv[1][0]` to get the numerical value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` are just integers, when you input '2' from argv, it reads the character '2' (which is equal to 50 in ASCII). In your second case, you input the int 2, hence the two different outputs. Your function is correct and so is the output.

Comment: The C standard allows `char` to be signed or unsigned, and it is signed by default in common C implementations, including Clang, GCC, and MSVC.

Comment: Yes, you're right my bad.